# How to subtract adjacent cell value from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to achieve this ?.

```
D1=N6-C1,
D2=N6-C2,
D3=N6-C3,
D4=N6-C4
```

And I have to apply this for more than 1000 cells. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [absolute & relative references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) together:

In D1 enter:
`=$N$6-C1`

Filling it down will modify formula as you need

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

In D1, enter `=N$6-C1` and fill down to D1000.

(It doesn't need to be `=$N$6-C1` as Excel already understands that the N is absolute)

[image]